# How do I disable Windows 7 PatchGuard?

Tags: windows-7, anti-virus

A quick search took me to some sites which provide a driver to disable it. However, they don't look trustable and I'd not want to install a rootkit.

What are some trustworthy options of disabling PatchGuard?

How can we disable patchguard for Windows 7?

Comment: I believe patchguard is part of the kernel, so you would need some sort of patch to load before the kernel does at boot time, at least this is how advanced Malware circumvents it.

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_Patch_Protection#Weaknesses):

> In January 2006, security researchers known by the pseudonyms "skape" and "Skywing" published a report that describes methods, some theoretical, through which Kernel Patch Protection might be bypassed. Skywing went on to publish a second report in January 2007 on bypassing KPP version 2, and a third report in September 2007 on KPP version 3. Also, in October 2006 security company Authentium developed a working method to bypass KPP.
>
> Nevertheless, **Microsoft has stated that they are committed to remove any flaws that allow KPP to be bypassed as part of its standard Security Response Center process. In keeping with this statement, Microsoft has so far released two major updates to KPP, each designed to break known bypass techniques in previous versions**

So since patching the kernel is wholly unsupported by Microsoft, there's no "trustworthy option" to disable it -- you're always going to have to rely on some dodgy hack.

Comment: Yes obviously Microsoft don't support it. If they would, it defeats the whole purpose of creating PatchGuard in the first place.... [So, we are asking for credible workarounds](http://serverfault.com/q/676812/87017).  Dodgy hacks are fine (and indeed the only way) as long as they are not malware.

Answer (score 2):

https://libertas.lt/code/patchguard/

I used this version, based on the work of Fyyre (http://fyyre.ivory-tower.de/). After installation on a test PC I kept an eye on outbound network traffic for a while in my router (Ubiquiti Edge) and didn't see anything. Fyyre's site also has Windows 7 SP1 and Windows 8 patchguard disablers.

This patchguard disabler only supports Windows Vista, 7, 8.1, and Tech Preview 10 64bit.